# PNY Nvidia GTX 580 horizontal lines artifacts

Tags: graphics-card

Just got an old PNY GTX 580 from a friend (read: ebay). It is most definitely broken and out of warranty. I am attempting to find out what's wrong with it so I can repair it.

Card output looks like this:
[image]

This is what GPU Z shows me:

[image]

Interestingly it can't seem to find the VRAM. If the VRAM is bad then how is it displaying anything at all? (Using system ram maybe?) Further, if the VRAM is bad, then is there anyway to replace it?

Any other thoughts are welcome and appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This does look like VRAM corruption - it's not unusual to see junk data like this but get some functionality.

Unless you're an expert solderer and have an identical card to scavenge the VRAM chips from (and even then I'm not sure how feasible a replacement would be), you'll just have to assume this card can't be fixed.

Comment: Also note that the GTX 580 is not *that* old...I thought PNY had two year GPU warranties, and it would almost certainly still be in that period (if only barely).

Comment: Two questions: could a corrupted bios be the problem (is it worth looking into)? And by friend I meant ebay so I'm not sure how the warranty works in that scenario, I assume I'm out of luck?

Comment: Check PNY's website about the warranty.

Comment: @jmathew - 1: I really doubt it would do this, but if you can find a dump of the BIOS it couldn't hurt to try flashing over it.  2: They may not require proof of purchase, I'd at least *try* first.  (I'd check on this before trying #1, because if they happen to check after the fact and see you've screwed with the BIOS you're sure to be handed a bill)

Comment: @PhillipR. Yea looks like they want proof of purchase. So I'm probably out of luck in that department

Comment: @Shinrai Sounds like a good plan. I'll try and get an rma, failing that, bios update. One last question to pick your brain. Is it more likely, the memory itself is bad or the connections to the chip (as in fractures in the solder) would yield that output?

Comment: @jmathew - Really depends on the design of the card, and I don't know these well enough to say for sure.  Naively I'd guess it's more likely to be a bad connection, just because this is a big heavy card.

Comment: @Shinrai Alright thanks for the help. Adds a last ditch effort of re-baking the solder with a heat gun.

Answer (score 0):

I have a 9-yo Zogis GXT-580. Four years ago it had a similar trouble, probably related to the GPU cold soldering that I resolved by baking it. Today these same (green) lines appeared, which GPU-Z bench test showed to be no memory as stated above. Fifteen minutes in the oven brought it to life, again.